# How I can access to WSDL 1.1 file from ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, service, wsdl

I have a WSDL 1.1 file which describes my Web Service. Now I need get access to its methods using ASP.NET 3.5

I tried to use wsdl.exe utility but I think that this utility use only WSDL 2.0 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between WSDL 1.1 and WSDL 2.0 for wsdl.exe. I just have an error in .wsdl file. This code:

```
<message name='PurchaseResponse'>
    <part name='result' element='xsd:string'/>
</message>
```

Must be:

```
<message name='PurchaseResponse'>
    <part name='result' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using VS 2008 
   Right click on the references folder in you project
   Select "Add Web Reference..."
   Enter the URL to your webservice
   In the Web reference name textbox type in how you would like to reference it.  So for an inventory Extension type "Inventory".

To create the object in code you would use Inventory.ProductSoapClient client = new Inventory.ProductSoapClient()

To call a method in you webservice client.Method();

Comment: I can add web reference but VS doesn't creates any proxy class to access methods of the service. If I add "Inventory" reference i have no class Inventory or etc. The fact is what WSDL service isn't asmx?wsdl at the end of url it's just .wsdl file in WSDL 1.1 format. I think VS2008 waited WSDL 2.0 from me

Answer (score 0):

I've installed .NET Framework 1.1 and SDK 1.1. Just for test, I thought its can help me, because .NET 1.1 works with WSDL 1.1 (SDK 1.1 and WSDL 1.1 its just coincidence, it's doen't mean what SDK 1.1 for WSDL 1.1 and/or SDK 2.0 for WSDL 2.0)
I have save error message then in case of using wsdl.exe from SDK 2.0

Error message sounds as: *Error: The element attribute is not allowed on encoded message parts. The erroneous part is named 'result' in message 'PurchaseResponse'.*

Part of code is:

```
<message name='PurchaseResponse'>
    <part name='result' element='xsd:string'/>
</message>
```